# Rails -ransack gem not working on heroku postgres db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

(1) my ransack search function works locally on my sqlite3 db
(2) when i search on deployed site i get this error in console
[here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n7m8.png)

this is my heroku console

```
2022-08-08T17:01:53.433036+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/turbo.min.js-a846cfe9aa92146457cc1c842185f5501c45f493ea69b21f1cdd191c039dee31.map" host=boxingappproject.herokuapp.com request_id=62afd5a1-7c64-4eed-bb53-e59f4ab4ab95 fwd="92.235.54.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=58293 protocol=https
```

here is my view

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>

  <!--Search if the name field contains...-->
  <%= f.label :blue_corner_cont%>
  <%= f.search_field :blue_corner_or_red_corner_or_date_cont, class: "input-group-text" %>
</div>
```

here is my controler

```
 def index
   
    #ransakc search
    @q= Fight.ransack(params[:q])
     @fights = @q.result
    
  end
```

my database is on latest migration both locally and deployed

Comment: I think this has less to do with ransack and more to do with turbo: https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/issues/122

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. It was working in my local environment, but not when deployed to heroku.

My heroku app worked after updating to the latest gem not yet published to RubyGems. In my gem file, I just switched from `gem 'ransack'` to

```
gem 'ransack', :github => 'activerecord-hackery/ransack', :branch => 'main'
```